# VB.NET disable right click on AxShockwaveFlash elements

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, axshockwaveflash

I've tried to disable the built-in right click menu of the shockwave flash element in my application, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to disable it in VB? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should disable the mouse right click event:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form ,IMessageFilter // after the name space
{     

     private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(this.Form1_FormClosed);
    }
    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
         //Filter out WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN/UP/DBLCLK
        if (m.Msg == 0xA4 || m.Msg == 0xA5 || m.Msg == 0xA6) return true;
        // Filter out WM_RBUTTONDOWN/UP/DBLCLK
        if (m.Msg == 0x204 || m.Msg == 0x205 || m.Msg == 0x206) return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This can give you a RightClick Disabled ShockWaveObject "only with 4 simple Steps"**

On your "Form" Add a Shockwave Flash control.

**1. Create a new Class file named "NoRightClickFlashControl.vb"**

Paste the bellow code into NoRightClickFlashControl.vb

```
Public Class NoRightClickFlashControl

Inherits AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
Private Const WM_RBUTTONDOWN As Integer = &H204

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case WM_RBUTTONDOWN
            ' Do nothing on right-click
            m.Result = New IntPtr(1)
            Return
    End Select
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

End Class
```

**2. Change the Name** of your ShockwaveObject "AxShockwaveFlash1" **to "NoRightClickFlashControl1"** on your Form.

Open your Form.Designer.vb file

**3. Change the code**  in between **'Initialize and SuspendLayout'** like bellow :

```
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()

'// Old is : Me.NoRightClickFlashControl1 = New AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash()

    '// Change like this
    Me.NoRightClickFlashControl1 = New Your_Project_NameSpace.NoRightClickFlashControl

    Me.SuspendLayout()
```

**Then at Last**, in  Form.Designer.vb near the "End Class" file -- **change the following** :

```
'// Old is : Friend WithEvents NoRightClickFlashControl1 As AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash

  '// Change Like this :
  Friend WithEvents NoRightClickFlashControl1 As NoRightClickFlashControl

End Class '// the End Class is just o understand.
```

All other coding is same to ShockwaveFlashObject - Load Movie, Play

It is **Done**

Press F5 to run! Enjoy!!!